# Почему код возвращает undefined вместо массива?

Tags: javascript

```
let nums = [153456, 123406, 124456, 323456, 123458, 123756];

function findKey (nums){
    let arr = nums;
    return arr;
};
console.log(findKey());
```

Comment: `console.log(findKey(???));`

Comment: Эта функция должна возвращать [153456, 123406, 124456, 323456, 123458, 123756] вместо undefined

Comment: Не должна, потому что в первый аргумент `nums` вы передали ничего, то есть `undefined`. Тот `let nums`, что снаружи функции, не имеет никакого значения в данном случае

Comment: Самое трудное в программировании - придумывать названия переменных.

Comment: "Трудно небось писать книжки? А всего трудней — обложки, правда? Их, верно, пишет Малин?" А.Линдгрен "Мы - на острове Сальткрока"

Answer (score 3):

Все очень просто! Вы забыли передать аргумент nums в функцию. Будет работать так: 
`console.log(findKey(nums));`

Answer (score 2):

Аргумент не передан, значит Ваш nums внутри функции undefined - вот он и возвращается